# Attempted to compile "zone.js" as an external module, but it looks like a global module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, angular

I have the "AngularClass" angular2-webpack-starter project
I have install all npm dependencies
Now I'm trying to install typings

typings.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "zone.js": "github:gdi2290/typed-zone.js#66ea8a3451542bb7798369306840e46be1d6ec89"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "angular-protractor": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/angular-protractor/angular-protractor.d.ts#64b25f63f0ec821040a5d3e049a976865062ed9d",
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654",
    "hammerjs": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/hammerjs/hammerjs.d.ts#74a4dfc1bc2dfadec47b8aae953b28546cb9c6b7",
    "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#4b36b94d5910aa8a4d20bdcd5bd1f9ae6ad18d3c",
    "node": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts#8cf8164641be73e8f1e652c2a5b967c7210b6729",
    "selenium-webdriver": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/selenium-webdriver/selenium-webdriver.d.ts#a83677ed13add14c2ab06c7325d182d0ba2784ea",
    "webpack": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/webpack/webpack.d.ts#95c02169ba8fa58ac1092422efbd2e3174a206f4"
  }
}
```

when I typed

```
sudo typings install
```

I got

```
derzunov:angular2-webpack-starter derzunov$ sudo typings install
typings ERR! message Attempted to compile "zone.js" as an external module, but it looks like a global module.

typings ERR! cwd /Users/derzunov/projects/Angular2/angular2-webpack-starter
typings ERR! system Darwin 15.4.0
typings ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/typings" "install"
typings ERR! node -v v4.4.4
typings ERR! typings -v 1.0.2

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

What does it mean?
Help! =))

Comment: I suspect it needs `-g` for a global install. `sudo install -g typings`

Comment: @SterlingArcher: No; this is an Angular pre-compiler thing.

Comment: @SLaks what am I doing wrong?

Comment: link of the project - https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Comment: `typings (npm install --global typings)` did this work for you?

Comment: I have installed typings already. This does not change anything

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Typings 1.0.x has some [breaking changes](https://github.com/typings/typings/releases/tag/v1.0.0). Put "zone.js" into "ambientDependencies" section and rename it to "globalDependencies"

Comment: I had the same problem and modifying the typings.json file as instructed above resolved my problems.

Comment: Works for me too. Don't be afraid to make the change even if a lot of other lines are under ambientDependencies.