# Angular2 + Visual Studio 2015 - Typings

Tags: visual-studio, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm having trouble with installing typings. I have the following line at the top of boot.ts:

```
///<reference path="./../typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts"/>
```

However, That typing is not installed in node_modules:

[image]

I have the typings.json file with the following:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160412134438",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515"
  }
}
```

From all the Google'ing, I should be able to run "typings install" to install it. But, I'm just not seeing it. When I run that command, all I see is:

[image]

What am I missing/doing incorrectly?

Comment: There is a command line tool called tsd to download typings from the mighty archive. Do not know how it works in VS.

Comment: @Thomas tsd is actually deprecated

Comment: What you are looking at in that `typings` folder is not the typing information you want to download for your own code, but the actual npm module that gives you the ability to download and manage them. You should create the `typings.json` in the root of your JavaScript application (likely next to the `node_modules` folder), and do a `typings install` from the command line. You might need to install the global `typings` command first though. See the [quick start](https://github.com/typings/typings#quick-start) for more help.

Comment: @poke Thanks for that ... guess half a year is too long for tech knowledge ;). New system looks awesome.

Comment: @poke Not sure, if that 2nd comment was for me or not. I do have the typings.json file, but still the "typings install" command doesnt install the typings. I ended up replacing the line like below and it is now compiling properly and working. Not sure if proper, but it IS working.

Original:
    ///<reference path="./../typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts"/>

New:
    /// <reference path="../node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api/typings/browser.d.ts" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found my answer here: [Attempted to compile "zone.js" as an external module, but it looks like a global module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263398/attempted-to-compile-zone-js-as-an-external-module-but-it-looks-like-a-global)

Summary from the above link:
Basically, the newest Typings install has new changes.

1. In typings.json file change "ambientDependencies" to "globalDependencies"
2. All the typings are saved/stored in /typings folder in the root of your project, not "node_modules" (where I was looking). Reference them accordingly